# How to merge two arrays with value compare - Google Analytics & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop

Stack, this job is making me desperate. What am I up to? I use the Google Analytics NodeJS SDK to get the most visited pages of my website. I let Google provide me the user-friendly URLs (slugs) to search the MongoDB database. So I store the three slugs of the most visited pages in an array and then run a normal MongoDB `Recording.find({slug: searchArr}` function. The Anayltics results are available in `result.data.rows`.

```
google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
  {
    auth: jwt,
    ids: 'ga:' + view_id,
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    metrics: 'ga:uniquePageviews',
    dimensions: 'ga:pagePath',
    sort: '-ga:uniquePageviews',
    filters: 'ga:pagePath=~/recordings/',
    'max-results': '3'
  },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      Sentry.captureException(err);
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'An error occurred.' });
    } else {
      let mostViewedFirst = {
        slug: result.data.rows[0][0].replace('/recordings/', ''),
        views: result.data.rows[0][1]
      };
      const mostViewedSecond = {
        slug: result.data.rows[1][0].replace('/recordings/', ''),
        views: result.data.rows[1][1]
      };
      const mostViewedThird = {
        slug: result.data.rows[2][0].replace('/recordings/', ''),
        views: result.data.rows[2][1]
      };
      let searchArr = [mostViewedFirst.slug, mostViewedSecond.slug, mostViewedThird.slug];
      let concatArr = [
        {
          slug: mostViewedFirst.slug,
          views: mostViewedFirst.views
        }, {
          slug: mostViewedSecond.slug,
          views: mostViewedSecond.views
        }, {
          slug: mostViewedThird.slug,
          views: mostViewedThird.views
        }];
      Recording.find({slug: searchArr},
        (err, recording) => {
          if (err) {
            Sentry.captureException(err);
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Most viewed recording could not be loaded.' });
          } else {
            res.json(recording.concat(concatArr));
          }
        }
      ).populate('genres')
        .populate('artists')
        .populate('show');
    }
  });
```

**Google Analytics SDK Response:**

```
  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "views": "148"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "views": "75"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "views": "68"
  }
```

**Mongoose Response:**

```
  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "title": "Recording A"
    ...
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "title": "Recording B"
    ...
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "title": "Recording C",
    ...
  }
```

In the next step I would like to apply the array output by Google to that of the MongoDB database. The value "slug" should match and the "views" should be inserted into the corresponding object.

With `res.json(recording.concat(concatArr));` I was able to display both objects in the JSON response:

```
  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "views": "148"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "views": "75"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "views": "68"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "title": "Recording A"
    ...
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "title": "Recording B"
    ...
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "title": "Recording C",
    ...
  }
```

**My desired result:**

```
  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "title": "Recording A"
    "views": "148"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "title": "Recording B"
    "views": "75"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "title": "Recording C",
    "views": "68"
  }
```

Unfortunately, I can't get the Analytics values array from Google to the MongoDB one. It is also possible that I have written some very complicated code - maybe the whole logic can be simplified by a for loop. I am open for any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var googleArray = [  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "views": "148"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "views": "75"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "views": "68"
  }];
  
var mongoArray = [  {
    "slug": "recording-a",
    "title": "Recording A"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-b",
    "title": "Recording B"
  },
  {
    "slug": "recording-c",
    "title": "Recording C"
  }];

// This is the important line:
var mergedArray = googleArray.map(x => Object.assign(x, mongoArray.find(y => y.id == x.id)));

// This is just for showing the output in this example:
alert(JSON.stringify(mergedArray, null, 2));
```